# Regex to match all variables, but exclude uppercase words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm a regex beginner, and I'm having some trouble excluding a pattern in my search. I have a domain specific language that uses capitalized words as keywords: These I'd like to ignore, but I'd like to capture all possible variable names.

Example variable names:

- VarWithCapitals
- variable
- var_with_snake_case
- var_with_{curly}_braces
- Var_with_The_{kitchen123}_Sink

Some example keywords:

- CMD
- DO WHILE ENDWHILE
- FOR

The regex I have so far matches everything but does not exclude the capitalized keywords:
`\b[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]*\b`

how can I exclude words containing only capitalized words but match my other variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude the rules you don't want

```
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]*\b
```

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Du4hz3/1/)

#### Explains:

- `(?!...)` [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), the following text must NOT match the following rule
- `(?![A-Z]+\b)` if the following text is made only with capitalized letters followed by a word boundary, fail the test